# Best way to say something affects another but only moderately?

Tags: word-choice

There is a saying that "Correlation does not imply causation."  I am trying to find the best way, preferrably in a word or short phrase, to explain when one thing really does have a causal effect on another, but the effect may not be strong.

This might be more clear with examples.  People tend to get better with experience, so years of experience really might cause someone to be more skilled.  But there are so many other factors (intensity of that experience, amount of study and practice, etc.) that the effect of experience might easily get swamped out and someone with fewer years of experience might be more skilled.

Similarly, exercise can help cause weight loss.  But diet and genetics often play a bigger role than amount of exercise in determining how much someone will weigh.

One phrase that I think comes close to my meaning is "loosely coupled", but I don't think that quite captures it and for people with a software development background it will carry a very [specific meaning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loosely_coupled).  So what is the best way to express this?

Comment: tangentially, minimally, moderately, greatly affects.

Comment: It is of course not true that "correlation does not *imply* causation". What's true is that correlation does not *equal* causation. That observed correlations lead us to test for causation tells us that indeed the one implies the other, and we test for the truth of that implication.

Comment: I think you may be interpreting the word "imply" differently from the way I mean it.  In formal logic and in the scientific community saying that "X implies Y" means that if X is true than Y must absolutely be true.  Wikipedia has a good discussion of the meaning and origins of that phrase here:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlation_does_not_imply_causation

Comment: ... I use that definition when I'm teaching maths. But it is improper to use it on a linguistics website without warning. It's not the principal sense in everyday English.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're looking for "***influence***". As in:

> Certainly diet and exercise ***influence*** weight regulation, but genetics and ingrained eating habits ***predispose*** many of us to gain weight.

Alternatives for *predispose* include ***bias***, ***sway***, and ***skew***, all of which mean to incline (ie make more liable) something towards a specific condition, without totally determining the outcome.

Comment: **Inform** is used to mean 'have a strong influence (on)': 3. To be a pervasive presence in [AHD] //3. to pervade or permeate with manifest effect: _A love of nature informed his writing._ [RHK Webster's]

Comment: Oh, good one. Do you think *inform* can be used for physical, real-world processes like weight gain or skill acquisition?

Comment: No, I think that the DO has to be a sentient's opinions / decisions / manifested skills /etc. Hence not an 'answer'.

Answer (score 1):

*[Related](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/related#Adjective)* (“Standing in relation or connection”),   *[linked](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/linked#Verb)* (“connected, either with links, or as if with links”), and *[connected](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/connected#Adjective)* all are possibilities.  (Note that *related*, like *[correlated](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/correlated)*, does not imply causation; and to some extent the same criticism applies to *linked* and *connected*.  For specificity, perhaps say *causally related, linked,* or *connected*.)

Answer (score 1):

My go-to way to categorize such impacts is by stating that the additional source as having a secondary or tertiary impact.

Answer (score -1):

Since you are trying to discount something from being the sole cause in a causality, you could use the term "not entirely." As in "The reason for [effect] is *not entirely* down to [cause].